# How to set height of LinearLyout as matchparent programmatically

Tags: height, android-linearlayout

I want to set the height of a Linear layout to match parent but not getting how can i do this? I am noob in android programming. I tried to find it on this site but couldn't  found. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
     LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);

     l.setLayoutParams(new 
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
     l.setLayoutParams(new WindowManager.LayoutParams());
     setContentView(l);
```

Comment: getting error "    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.WindowManager$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams
"

Comment: You have to remove the CoordinatorLayout from your xml file